# Rewrite folder(s) name(s) in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a folder named *folder1*, and *folder1* contains some php files

**FOLDER1 FILES**

*index.php*

*user.php*

I want to rewrite only the folder name to *new_name* with htaccess so that I can access *folder1* files using the new name, say `example.com/new_name/user.php` Instead of `example.com/folder1/user.php`

I've already tried the code below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

ReweiteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]

RewriteRule ^new_name(.*)$ /folder1/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

To rewrite only the folder name try rule with new_name/* and without 301 redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^new_name\/(.*)$ /folder1/$1 [L,NC]

ReweiteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: I also want to redirect users accessing *folder1* to *new_name* externally. How do I achieve this?